# Merge results of single JSON output with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a JSON array as per below:

```
{
"aaData": [
    {
        "Date_time": "23",
        "traffic": "22",
        "direction": "sent"
    },
    {
        "Date_time": "24",
        "traffic": "55",
        "direction": "sent"
    },
    {
        "Date_time": "25",
        "traffic": "60",
        "direction": "sent"
    },
    {
        "Date_time": "26",
        "traffic": "43",
        "direction": "sent"
    },
    {
        "Date_time": "27",
        "traffic": "50",
        "direction": "sent"
    },
    {
        "Date_time": "23",
        "traffic": "50",
        "direction": "received"
    },
    {
        "Date_time": "24",
        "traffic": "42",
        "direction": "received"
    },
    {
        "Date_time": "25",
        "traffic": "52",
        "direction": "received"
    },
    {
        "Date_time": "26",
        "traffic": "47",
        "direction": "received"
    },
    {
        "Date_time": "27",
        "traffic": "36",
        "direction": "received"
    }
]
}
```

What I'd like to do with it is combine all the results with the same date into a single entry - so for date_time 23 I want it to appear like this

```
    "Date_time": "23",
    "traffic-sent": "22",
    "traffic-received": "50"
```

I'd like to do this with PHP if possible? The data is coming from two separate mySQL queries, coming from to different mySQL databases. I've tried combining the output of the query to do what I need (tried Joins and Unions) but can't get past the separation of the results as per my first example.

The part of the SQL query creating the JSON looks like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $model[$i]['Date_time'] = $row['the_day'];
    $model[$i]['traffic']   = $row['traffic'];
    $model[$i]['direction'] = $row['TABLE_NAME'];
    $i++;
}
```

And the SQL looks like this:

```
(SELECT
DAY(`Time`) AS the_day,
count(accounts.accName) AS traffic,
"sent" AS TABLE_NAME
FROM
bss.ss_sent LEFT JOIN bss.accounts ON ss_sent.Customer = accounts.accName
WHERE
YEARWEEK(`Time`) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)
AND 
Customer != " "
AND
accShortName = "QRR"
GROUP BY
the_day)

UNION   

(SELECT
DAY(Date_time) AS the_day,
count(AS_Task) AS traffic,
"received" AS TABLE_NAME
FROM
im_stats.as_counter
WHERE
AS_Task = "QRR3 Incoming"
AND
YEARWEEK(Date_time) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY
the_day
Order by the_day)
```

IF anyone can advise of a way to combine the results I'd very much appreciate it.

UPDATE:

This is how I've entered Populus's code:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $model[$i]['Date_time'] = $row['the_day'];
    $model[$i]['traffic']   = $row['traffic'];
    $model[$i]['direction'] = $row['TABLE_NAME'];
    $i++;
}

$combined = array();

foreach ($model as $val) {
    $date_time = $val['Date_time'];
    if (!isset($combined[$date_time)) {
        $combined[$date_time] = array(
            'Date_time' => $date_time,
            'traffic_sent' => 0,
            'traffic_received' => 0,
    );
}
if ('received' == $val['direction']) {
    $combined[$date_time]['traffic_received'] += $val['traffic'];
} else {
    $combined[$date_time]['traffic_sent'] += $val['traffic'];
}
}




header('Content-type: application/json');

print json_encode(array('aaData' => $combined), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: You didn't include the SQL statement that you used

Comment: As @Populus is getting at, this may be able to be done with SQL. Post what you're using as your query now so we are able to tweak it.

Comment: Sorry! SQL added - hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could probably be done using SQL (which you haven't provided), but if you really want PHP:

```
$combined = array();

foreach ($model as $val) {
    $date_time = $val['Date_time'];
    if (!isset($combined[$date_time])) {
        $combined[$date_time] = array(
            'Date_time' => $date_time,
            'traffic_sent' => 0,
            'traffic_received' => 0,
        );
    }
    if ('received' == $val['direction']) {
        $combined[$date_time]['traffic_received'] += $val['traffic'];
    } else {
        $combined[$date_time]['traffic_sent'] += $val['traffic'];
    }
}
```

Your desired array is now in `$combined`. If you don't want the keys, you can remove it:

```
$result = array_values($combined);
```

Comment: Thanks Populus - I added the SQL just a moment ago. I'll try the code you have provided and let you know how I get on, thanks again

Comment: Populus - I appreciate you taking the time to respond, and I'm sure the issue is with me rather than you, but sadly I'm unable to get your code to work. Thanks again for your help

Comment: from the actual page, I get nothing (it doesn't even pause as it's loading). I've added your code and how I've added it to mine in the post above

Comment: can you add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your script? It may give us some more information.

Comment: Here you go: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']' in /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/scriptStats/json/sentreceivedMSS.php on line 70 . I changed the ( to a [ and now get this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/scriptStats/json/sentreceivedMSS.php on line 70.

Comment: I've added a couple of brackets in which seems to have solved the problem with the line 70 error messages, I now get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/scriptStats/json/sentreceivedMSS.php on line 90

Comment: Ignore the last comment Populus - I re-copy & pasted your original code, tweaked the square bracket and it's working perfectly. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks for the spot on the typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['direction'] == 'sent')
        $dt[$row['Date_time']]['traffic-sent'] += $row['traffic'];
    elseif ($row['direction'] == 'recieved')
        $dt[$row['Date_time']]['traffic-recieved'] += $row['traffic'];
}

foreach ($dt as $date) {
    echo "Date_time: " . key($date) . ",<br/>" .
        "traffic_sent: " . $date['traffic-sent'] . ",<br/>" .
        "traffic-recieved: " . $date['traffic-recieved'] . "<br/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry Switcher, I've replaced my code with yours, when I refresh the page it appears to be thinking about it for a moment or two, but doesn't return any results. I've no doubt I'm doing something wrong but can't see what